# Using Apollo, how can I distinguish newly created objects?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

My use case is the following:

I have a list of comments that I fetch using a GraphQL query. When the user writes a new comment, it gets submitted using a GraphQL mutation. Then I'm using `updateQueries` to append the new comment to the list.

In the UI, I want to highlight the newly created comments. I tried to add a property `isNew: true` on the new comment in `mutationResult`, but Apollo removes the property before saving it to the store (I assume that's because the `isNew` field isn't requested in the gql query).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The date when the comment was published is available?

Comment: I don't think using the date is a solid solution. How are you gonna detect if the comment is new? Do you check if it was created in the last 10 seconds? Or in the last 100 milliseconds? Each one of those has its own problems.

Comment: "isNew" is added to the first comment at some fixed point in time. Every comment before this time is no longer new.

Comment: And where should I keep that "fixed point in time"? I don't want to use a global variable. Also, the page contains multiple posts, each one with its own list of comments. So I prefer a solution that's contained within the CommentList component.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you mean by "newly created objects". If it is authentication based application with users that can login, you can compare the `create_date` of comment with some `last_online` date of user. If the user is not forced to create an account, you can store such an information in local storage or cookies (when he/she last time visited the website).

---

On the other hand, if you think about real-time update of comments list, I would recommend you take a look at [`graphql-subscriptions`](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions) with use of `websockets`. It provides you with reactivity in your user interface with use of `pub-sub` mechanism. Simple use case - whenever new comment is added to a post, every user/viewer is notified about that, the comment can be appended to the comments list and highlighted in a way you want it.

In order to achieve this, you could create a `subscription` called `newCommentAdded`, which client would subscribe to and every time a new comment is being created, the `server` side of the application would notify (`publish`) about that.

Simple implementation of such a case could look like that

```
const Subscription = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Subscription',
    fields: {
        newCommentAdded: {
            type: Comment, // this would be your GraphQLObject type for Comment
            resolve: (root, args, context) => {
                return root.comment;
            }
        }
    }
});


// then create graphql schema with use of above defined subscription
const graphQLSchema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: Query, // your query object
    mutation: Mutation, // your mutation object
    subscription: Subscription
});
```

The above part is only the `graphql-js` part, however it is necessary to create a `SubscriptionManager` which uses the `PubSub` mechanism.

```
import { SubscriptionManager, PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

const pubSub = new PubSub();

const subscriptionManagerOptions = {
    schema: graphQLSchema,
    setupFunctions: {
        newCommentAdded: (options, args) => {
            newCommentAdded: {
                 filter: ( payload ) => {
                     // return true -> means that  the subscrition will be published to the client side in every single case you call the 'publish' method
                     // here you can provide some conditions when to publish the result, like IDs of currently logged in user to whom you would publish the newly created comment
                     return true;
            }
        }
    },
    pubsub: pubSub
});

const subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager(subscriptionManagerOptions);

export { subscriptionManager, pubSub };
```

And the final step is to `publish` newly created comment to the client side when it is necessary, via above created `SubscriptionManager` instance. You could do that in the mutation method creating new comment, or wherever you need

```
// here newComment is your comment instance
subscriptionManager.publish( 'newCommentAdded', { comment: newComment } );
```

In order to make the `pub-sub` mechanism with use of `websockets`, it is necessary to create such a server alongside your main server. You can use the [`subscriptions-transport-ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subscriptions-transport-ws) module.

The biggest advantage of such a solution is that it provides reactivity in your application (real-time changes applied to comments list below post etc.). I hope that this might be a good choice for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm actually not interested in new comments coming from the server. I only care about comments that the current user is writing.

Answer (score 0):

I could see this being done a couple of ways. You are right that Apollo will strip the isNew value because it is not a part of your schema and is not listed in the queries selection set. I like to separate the concerns of the server data that is managed by apollo and the front-end application state that lends itself to using redux/flux or even more simply by managing it in your component's state.

Apollo gives you the option to supply your own redux store. You can allow apollo to manage its data fetching logic and then manage your own front-end state alongside it. Here is a write up discussing how you can do this: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/redux.html.

If you are using React, you might be able to use component lifecycle hooks to detect when new comments appear. This might be a bit of a hack but you could use `componentWillReceiveProps` to compare the new list of comments with the old list of comments, identify which are new, store that in the component state, and then invalidate them after a period of time using `setTimeout`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {

  // Compute a diff.
  const oldCommentIds = new Set(this.props.data.allComments.map(comment => comment.id));
  const nextCommentIds = new Set(newProps.data.allComments.map(comment => comment.id));
  const newCommentIds = new Set(
    [...nextCommentIds].filter(commentId => !oldCommentIds.has(commentId))
  );
  this.setState({
    newCommentIds
  });

  // invalidate after 1 second
  const that = this;
  setTimeout(() => {
    that.setState({
      newCommentIds: new Set()
    })
  }, 1000);
}

// Then somewhere in your render function have something like this.
render() {
  ...
  {
    this.props.data.allComments.map(comment => {
      const isNew = this.state.newCommentIds.has(comment.id);
      return <CommentComponent isNew={isNew} comment={comment} />
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

The code above was right off the cuff so you might need to play around a bit. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently doing something very similar to your answer :) But I'm looking for a less hacky solution.