# Apollo Server Subscriptions not working

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I've made a GraphQL backend using Apollo Server, Sequelize (for the ORM), MySQL (DB) and Express (Web Server).

I have also added subscriptions, which the problem is there.
I can't even reach the WS endpoint using a websocket tester.

Can someone review my code and tell me what the problem is? I looked in the docs, other stackoverflow questions and I can't find any solution.

The code: https://github.com/seklyza/graphqlsubscriptions

Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make 2 Servers one for the app which uses the `express` server and one for the websocket. It could look like this.

GraphQL express server:

```js
...

graphQLServer = express();

const GRAPHQL_PORT = 4000;

graphQLServer.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress((request) => {
  return {
    schema: executableSchema,
  };
}));

graphQLServer.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
}));

graphQLServer.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/graphql`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
});

...
```

websocket server for subscriptions:

```js
...

const WS_PORT = 8080;

const websocketServer = createServer((request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(404);
  response.end();
});

websocketServer.listen(WS_PORT, () => console.log( // eslint-disable-line no-console
  `Websocket Server is now running on http://localhost:${WS_PORT}`
));

const subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager({
  schema: executableSchema,
  pubsub: pubsub,
  setupFunctions: { /* your subscription channels */ },
});

subscriptionServer = new SubscriptionServer({
  subscriptionManager: subscriptionManager
}, {
  server: websocketServer,
  path: '/',
});

...
```

And you need some sort of publication subscription service, we use `pubSub`. It is included in the server file and looks like this:

```js
import {
  PubSub
} from 'graphql-subscriptions';

const pubsub = new PubSub();

export {
  pubsub
};
```

Comment: I also did that using 2 servers which did not work. I will try again...

Comment: By the way, how do I specify in GraphiQL the subscription server URL?

Comment: Sorry i do not know how to specify the subscription server

Comment: It still doesn't work. I can't even connect to the WS server using a websocket client. Look at the new code at GitHub.

Comment: Could you try to update the `subscriptions-transport-ws` package and use the `subscriptionServer = new SubscriptionServer({
  subscriptionManager: subscriptionManager
}, {
  server: websocketServer,
  path: '/',
});`

Comment: Does the console log that the websocket server is running?
Is the graph i QL running?

Comment: I updated the package, added the path, and yes, the console.log is working. But I still can't connect to the WS server (ws:// url). I think it is a problem in the subscriptions-transport-ws package.

Comment: You could try to add an output to the `const wsServer = createServer((req, res) => {
console.log("here");
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
})` and in the browser route to localhost:5000. If you see the output than youre connected. But of course cannot use that route because it returns `404` error

Answer (score 0):

You can create some web socket server wrapper which implements `start` method which will be responsible for creating and running the `WSServer`, as well as it will create a `SubscriptionServer` with use of `SubscriptionManager`

```js
// in subscription.js
import { PubSub, SubscriptionManager } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

const pubSub = new PubSub();

let subscriptionManagerOptions = {
    schema: schema, // this is your graphql schema
    setupFunctions: {
        // here come your setup functions
    },
    pubSub: pubSub
};

const subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager(subscriptionManagerOptions);

export { pubSub, subscriptionManager };
```

After we have the `subscriptionManager` created, we can now implement the `WSServer`

```js
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { SubscriptionServer } from 'subscription-transport-ws';
import { subscriptionManager } from './subscription';

const webSocketServerWrapper = {
    start: function(port){

        const webSocketServer = createServer((request, response) => {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end();
        });    

        webSocketServer.listen(port, () => {
            console.log('WSServer listening on port ' + port);
        });

        new SubscriptionServer({
            subscriptionManager,
            onSubscribe: (message, options, request) => {
                return Promise.resolve(Object.assign({}, options, {}));
            }
        }, webSocketServer);

    }
};

export default webSocketServerWrapper;
```

Now you can import the `webSocketServerWrapper` in the initialisation file like `index.js` and simply run `webSocketServerWrapper.start(PORT);`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334805/using-apollo-how-can-i-distinguish-newly-created-objects/42339660#42339660), the second answer which I wrote, you can find a code responsible for creating example subscription and how it should be handled.

Comment: Look at the other answer's comments, and see what the problem is.

Comment: How do you try to connect to your ws server?

Comment: So what was the problem?